# Unable to sign out in a Rails app, using Devise gem, no route matches /users/sign_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I know there are dozens of questions on different sites about this issue. I have tried a lot of things, and I still can't get the link with DELETE method to work.

I've created an empty rails application

Versions:

- devise 2.0.4
- rails: 3.2.2
- Ruby: 1.9.2
- RVM: 1.10.3

After I installed devise gem, I ran these commands:

```
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise User
```

Fixes I have tried are below:

Initial link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %>
```

I added the delete method, in ticks and without them:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => 'delete' %>
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Added this to application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

I uncommented these lines in assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
= require jquery
= require jquery_ujs
```

I also tried getting the GET link to work, changed this line from config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.sign_out_via = : delete
```

to this:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get if Rails.env.test?
```

No matter what I try, DELETE links result in this:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

GET links don't work as well:

No route matches [GET] "/"

I have tried restarting the server, of course.

Rake routes contains this:

```
 destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in devise.rb

find `config.sign_out_via = :delete`

change to `config.sign_out_via = :get`

if you use :get make sure you are using :method = :get and if you are using :delete using :method => :delete in your link

in production you may have to swap it round, so you should use an if statement to check RAILS_ENV

In your example you are probably running in development mode and not test, which is why it's probably not working.

And restart your server as it's an initialiser.

Comment: Straight simple answer. I have figured out Heroku used :GET and makes the code break on production (Heroku), so instead of changing it to `:get`, I had to set them as list such that it can handle both requests, then I have `config.sign_out_via = :delete, :get` and that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This helper always works for me:

```
link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete
```

Maybe you are not logged in properly? You could check with `if current_user`

Comment: I'm logged in, the logout links are shown only if user_signed_in? is true.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your routes file?

Specifically the devise_for call

You could also try setting the path explicitly

`devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_out: 'sign_out' }`