# Rails- devise not working http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've looked through all of the post on this problem, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I hope I'm not missing something obvious, but I'm new to rails and nothing is working.

I get this error when trying to sign out with devise

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

Here's my header

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

This is the line that's giving me problems, but all my other lines work fine

```
<li><%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
```

And my application.js looks good

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

Devise is setup to logout via

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

rake routes gives me

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) 
PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
               links GET    /links(.:format)               links#index
                     POST   /links(.:format)               links#create
            new_link GET    /links/new(.:format)           links#new
           edit_link GET    /links/:id/edit(.:format)      links#edit
                link GET    /links/:id(.:format)           links#show
                     PATCH  /links/:id(.:format)           links#update
                     PUT    /links/:id(.:format)           links#update
                     DELETE /links/:id(.:format)           links#destroy
                root GET    /                              links#index
```

I'm not sure where the problem lies and don't know what else to try.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No route matches \[GET\] "/users/sign\_out"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567863/no-route-matches-get-users-sign-out)

Comment: I tried all of those solutions and none of them worked. It hasn't been active for awhile, so I decided to create a new question

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server since installing Devise? Also what does running 'rake routes' output?

Comment: I have and it doesn't work. I updated the question to show what 'rake routes' outputs

Answer (score 4):

Try adjusting devise.rb to the following:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

You will need to restart your rails server for the configuration to apply properly.

Comment: Been using devise for years and this bug came up after switching to rails 4.2 from 4.1.  Changing the method worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898892/unable-to-sign-out-in-a-rails-app-using-devise-gem-no-route-matches-users-sig

Comment: @nmares12 Just remember to not use `<li><%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>` in te view while `config.sign_out_via = :get`