# Ruby on Rails application not working well on Heroku

Tags: heroku, devise, carrierwave

When I pushed my application to heroku yesterday, it functioned well. But this morning it starts misbehaving.

**Two Problems**

1. I have used Carrierwave to upload pictures into the app and it works well on my local app with no problem, **after its deployed to heroku and worked very well too, but few minutes later, I get 404 Error** and picture not loading. See the Console error below:

[image]

2. I have an admin made from Administrate and Devise for authentication. working well on local app and worked also after deploy but Today, when I go to admin endpoint and sign on, I dont get to be able to sign out and get I get `no route error`.

[image]

Am saving/uploading images as a file from carrierwave.

**carrierwave image uploader/image_uploader.rb**

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [263, 263]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

**Question**

> Why does it work sometimes and why doesn't it work sometimes or what am I doing wrong?

**Source Code**

https://github.com/AfolabiOlaoluwa/LawVille

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What rails helper are you using to display your images? 
Signing out is a DELETE route, not a GET route, make sure you've added the delete method to your link helper. If you are using tools such as PJAX for loading your page content this may cause your delete links to break

Comment: @Viro this is what I have for signing out `<% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => 'button'  %>
    <% end %>`
It works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't, how can I refactor this if its the problem?

Comment: Your sign_out link looks good to me, try to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898892/unable-to-sign-out-in-a-rails-app-using-devise-gem-no-route-matches-users-sig

Comment: That SOLVED Problem 1 I did append my devise config (`config.sign_out_via = :delete, :get`) setting for sign_out to handle `:get`. Thanks. How about Problem 2? Here is the helper am using to call my thumbnail image `<%= image_tag @lawyer.image.thumb.url %>`. Do I need to set http method on it too? Refer to the question for Error Image, it's a get error too.

Comment: The get method is the right one, looks like it can't find it on your server (404)
Look on your server if the file is indeed present, run the following:
$ heroku run bash
$ cd path_to_your_uploaded_images
$ ls

and see if the image you uploaded is there.
Could you also put your carrierwave uploader file?

Comment: @Viro after running `cd /uploads/lawyer/image/2/thumb_young-female-attorney-reviewing-law-books-in-library.jpg`,  I get: `No such file or directory`. but what baffles me is if its a newly uploaded image, it works, but won't view the second time.

Comment: Try using only <%= image_tag @lawyer.image.thumb %>

Comment: @Viro. that also didnt work. I asked heroku few question and I learnt Heroku has a read-only filesystem, so uploads must be stored on S3 and cannot be cached in the public directory. So, I did a workaround to cache directory such that I set a new action called `cache_dir` in my Uploader classes to the tmp directory, such that my code has this: `def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end`
This is working very well now.